# Why does padding add to the visible width of an element even when box-sizing is set to border-box?

Tags: html, padding, css

So I was coding using Semantic-ui, and I have two toggle boxes (check boxes) next to each other in a flexbox container. When the window size is reduced, they wrap around so that one is on top of the other.

To get them to spread out a little, I added both right and bottom padding of around 5px. However I noticed a strange behaviour. Padding would cause the boxes to move apart horizontally, but when stacked vertically there was no space between them, even though there was bottom padding on each box.

Further investigation showed that the `box-sizing` property of the check boxes was set to `border-box`. After reading up, I found that the `border-box` box model calculates the width and height to include the padding and the border.

The checkboxes have a height of 1.5rem assigned.

My question is as follows. As is my understanding, padding shouldn't change the size of the element when  using border-box. However this only seems to be true if definite dimensions are set as shown in the linked jsfiddle. Height is set, so the bottom padding isn't added on as an extra. But width isn't and right padding has an effect on the visible width of the divs.

Why is this the case? Surely padding should have no effect on the size of the element (unless set to something ridiculous, larger than the element itself), irrespective on whether I've defined a definite width or left it to be calculated?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Astridax/8cd48emn/

Please try and toggle the paddings using dev tools to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

*As is my understanding, padding shouldn't change the size of the element when using border-box.*

This is where you're confused. Here's what the spec has to say on this subject: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0

> **border-box**
>
> The specified width and height (and respective min/max
>   properties) on this element determine the border box of the element.
>   That is, any padding or border specified on the element is laid out
>   and drawn inside this specified width and height. The content width
>   and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths
>   of the respective sides from the specified ‘width’ and ‘height’
>   properties. As the content width and height cannot be negative
>   ([CSS21], section 10.2), this computation is floored at 0.

The actual effect of setting `box-sizing` to `border-box` is that *specified* widths will be said to include the border and the padding.  The spec says nothing about *unspecified* widths, which are therefore treated as normal - as wide as they need to be to incorporate both the content and the padding and the border.

Edit:

What you're implying should happen is actually impossible to do, for the following reason.  Imagine you have content in a `div` such that the `auto` width *of the content alone* would be 500px exactly.  Then throw a 20px padding around that.

```
#myDiv {
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
```

No problem yet - you have a 540px wide `div` with the box-sizing at `content-box` by default.

Okay, so lets change the `box-sizing` to `border-box`.

```
#myDiv {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
```

What you're suggesting should happen is that the padding should now be ignored.  So we have a `div` with 500px worth of content, we're going to now include the padding within that 500px instead of extending the width of the `div`.  But wait - now the content box has shrunk to 460px to allow for the padding and the overall size of the box is 500px.  But wait, we're not supposed to be accounting for the padding when calculating the width, so we'd better render the div at 460px right?

You see the problem?  You could go on infinitely like this.

Comment: This is where the spec isn't very clear, at least not to me. What does "specified width and height" refer to, exactly? Anything that isn't the initial value `auto`? "Specified value" has a very definite meaning in CSS, and it is not "anything that isn't the initial value". It looks like the box-sizing spec needs some clarification.

Comment: *specified width and height (and respective min/max properties) on this element* seems to be clearly referring to the CSS height and width properties. In the OP's example he has not specified the width, so the `border-box` rules don't apply (after all, how would this possibly work - if you think about it what the OP is asking for is logically impossible).

Comment: That's what I mean by "anything other than the initial value" - because one could still set width: auto, but it would still effectively be the same as not setting it at all. That would make sense to me, but I still think the spec could be clearer about this.

Comment: I'd agree with @BoltClock here. I know the spec mentions specified widths, however it isn't very clear on what happens when width and height aren't set. It evidently responds as if it were using the normal box model as you have pointed out, but is this intentional?
It isn't necessarily logically impossible. The width property could be calculated using the element contents and then padding and border sizes subtracted as defined in the spec as if height and width were explicitly defined. That is at least what I would have expected to have happened from border-box.

Comment: @BoltClock "auto" is not specifying a height or width, "auto" is instructing the browser to calculate the height or width.

Comment: @Astridax I've added some more information to my answer explaining the logical flaw in the behaviour you're wanting.

Comment: Like I said, that makes sense to me in a natural sentence, but only when I don't consider how [CSS defines "specified value"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specified-value). To be clear, I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying the spec is hazy (and that can be said for many parts of CSS3, much to my annoyance).

Comment: @BoltClock you're looking at the wrong spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-cascade-3-20131003/#cascaded-value but you still have a point. They seem to be actually talking about the "cascaded value" rather than the "specified value".  I think this is a mistake in the spec though, not the implementation, for the reasons already stated above.

Comment: Yeah, either way it's still resulting in the initial value. I'm sure they simply meant "specified" what it would have meant in context and I'm just overanalyzing.

Comment: @gnack In your above edit, it takes the width property (500px) and then applies the padding and border making the final calculated width 460px.  

For 'width: auto' why doesn't the browser calculate initial dimensions (e.g 500px) without padding etc and then subtract the assigned padding/border? This would still result in a width of 460px as before. Kind of similar to flex-basis, an initial size before distributing free space. I can't see why defined dimensions are required to use border-box. IE used to use a border-box style box model by default and didn't require defined widths.

Comment: @BoltClock I suppose the mantra is, if you cared so much about the dimensions to use border-box, you would set them yourself not leave the browser to calculate an initial size. I do think this needs clarification in the spec though.

Comment: @Astridax I see where you're coming from on a theoretical level, but in practice I'm having trouble conceiving of a case where you would want border-box behaviour to be applied to non-cascade-valued elements, so I think the debate is mostly academic here.